# How to rank the position of students based on percentange

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I hope you are will be fine.

I am stuck in finding the ranks of students based on percentage.

I have Excel table having multiple columns, concerning columns are **Percentage** and **Position**. My data set starts from *Row 25 = R25(in excel)*

**I am using following formula to calculate the percentage of the students based on obtained marks and total marks**

`=IF(V25="F","",N25/O25)`

> Where Column V includes pass or fail (in case of fail "F"), column N includes obtained marks and column O includes total marks

It produces the correct output as required:

[image]

Now comes to the real problem. Finding the rank/position of student.

**I am using RANK.EQ formula to calculate the rank/position of the students based on percentage**

`=IF(V25="F","Nil",RANK.EQ(P25,[Percentage]))`

It also produces the correct output as per formula:

[image]

**complete pic = >**

[image]

**Now what I want**

> The two student who obtains 80% marks are ranked as 1 (according to data set)
>
> Now the student who obtains *74% marks should be ranked as 2 instead of 3* and so on

Here is the clear picture of what I require:

[image]

I already tried the =SUMPRODUCT(), =MATCH(), =COUNTIF() etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got something I hope you can adapt to your needs. I replied your data this way:

[image]

As you can see, formula in column B returns ranking as you wish. To get this,I used an array formula:

```
=IF(A1="";"";SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF($A$1:$A$6>A1;$A$1:$A$6);$A$1:$A$6)>0;1))+1)
```

> **NOTE:** Because this in an array formula, it must be entered into cell pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> or it
>   won't work! You will know if you did it properly if your formula shows `{` at start and `}` at end.

The trick here is you want to rank your data in descendant order, but excluding duplicates. The array formula first gets an array of values higher than criteria (number in row), and then count how many **unique** values are in that array. If 0, it means is the highest value, so its rank is 1 (that explains the `+1` at end of formula). If count returns 1, means there is an **unique** value higher than criteria. so its rank is 2 (count of 1 + we add 1 = 2), and so on...

Hope you can adapt this to your needs.

For this I used info shown here:

> **[Count unique values among duplicates](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/count-unique-values-among-duplicates-8d9a69b3-b867-490e-82e0-a929fbc1e273)**

Comment: Thanks a lot Foxfire And Burns And Burns